# Put a button on top of toolbar in linearLayout(android kotlin)

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to put a button on top of a toolbar in linearLayout like in the photo[image].Is there any way to do that?

**Here is my xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/constr"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SettingsAct.SettingsActiv">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarSettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorAccent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/constr"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SettingsAct.SettingsActiv">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarSettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorAccent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: haha you must hate me today :P at least that is finished already :D thanks again!(I will vote you in 10 minutes !!)

Comment: No I don't hate you!